# Finite Element Method and ElementMeshInterpolation issue in v10.3

Tags: bugs, interpolation, finite-element-method

**Bug introduced in 10.3**

---

I recently installed Mathematica v10.3 and checked a project I was working on few months ago under Mathematica v10.1.

In this project I solve a PDE with `NDSolve` and Finite Element Method over a 2D anulus region and I and `ContourPlot` that solution.

Under v10.1 (and v10.2) the solution appear like this:

[image: 10.1 solution]

Under v10.3 the solution appear like this:

[image: 10.2]

The source code is exactly the same.

At the beginning I was convinced the problem was with NDSolve (and this question reflected that, I later edited). After more investigation I discovered the solution in the two releases is nearly the same.

You can reproduce the problem running:

```
Import["http://bit.ly/cp103issue"]
```

I searched on the documentation, news section, but I didn't find anything that could explain this or restore the previous behavior.

Any chance to understand the reason of the changed behavior and eventually restore the old?

## UPDATE

The problem is not related to ContourPlot but to the `InterpolatingFunction` returned by NDSolve (thanks to JasonB). Probably the InterpolatingFunction is built under the cover by a call to `ElementMeshInterpolation`. Indeed the following code in Mathematica 10.3 returns result completely different from the results in Mathematica 10.2.

```
<<NDSolve`FEM`
{Ri,Ro}={3000000.,6371000.};
rgn=RegionDifference[Disk[{0.,0.},Ro],Disk[{0.,0.},Ri]];
mesh=ToElementMesh[rgn];
grid=mesh["Coordinates"];
vog=(Exp[-Norm[#]^2/Ri^2])&/@grid;
ListContourPlot[MapThread[Append,{grid,vog}],Epilog->{Point[grid]},PlotLegends->Automatic]
if=ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh},vog];
ContourPlot[if[x,y],{x,y}\[Element]mesh,PlotLegends->Automatic,Epilog->{Point[grid]}]
TakeLargest[(if@@@grid-vog),20]
```

In 10.3:

[image: Mathematica 10.3]

In 10.2 (after som InterpolatingFunction::dmval message):

[image: Mathematica 10.2]

As you can see, in 10.2, the largest differences in "interpolation errors" are negligible, while in 10.3 they are even greather than the actual expected value.

The problem appear more specifically related with the "scale" of the mesh. Indeed if you change the sizes:

```
{Ri,Ro}={3000000.,6371000.}/10^6;
```

all apear fine:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Unless you can post some kind of example it is hard to figure it out, sorry

Comment: @JasonB Of course, just asking if someone is aware of some change in the FEM framework between 10.2 and 10.3... I'll try to prepare a reduced example if possible...

Comment: What loading/deformation? Plane stress 2 point, 4 point forces deformation/ stress plots? Solves an isotropic  2D stress function pde?

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, the plots shoud represents the modulus and horizontal component of the displacement vector; there is a load on the volume, horizontal outward on the x axis and vertical inward on the y axis, that gradually canges in-between; there is an essential homogeneus boundary condition on the inner border, and natural homogeneus on the outer. The material is composed of many isothropic anulus with differents Lamé coefficients.

Comment: The stress/deformation results are essentially the same. Extra features introduced elsewhere perhaps reduce the display/appearance .. that you can ignore until WRI would correct later on.

Comment: @unlikely, there is something going on here - and we can see it without the plots even.  Evaluate the following in both versions and you'll get a different result:  `testSolution[[2]][0, -4.8 10^6]`

Comment: Or compare the results of `Plot[Norm@Through[testSolution[x, -4.8 10^6]], {x, -200000, 200000}]` - which are really qualitatively different.  Do you have any intuitive understanding of what the function should look like, and which one of those might be right?

Comment: @JasonB On the single point (first comment) I get a match in the two versions. About the plot along a line (second comment)... When in my edit I wrote "the solution in the two releases is nearly the same" is because I compared the `"ValuesOnGrid"` of the `InterpolatingFunction`-s and I had a perfect match. Maybe there is some issue with the `InterpolatingFunction`?

Comment: Can you confirm that you get better results with setting the following system option: `SetSystemOptions[
 "FiniteElementOptions" -> {"CacheInterpolationElements" -> False}]`?

Comment: @user21 Yes, thanks

Answer (score 10):

Too long to make as a comment, so I'll post this non-answer as an answer.

I just want to point out that this definitely is not a `ContourPlot` problem, and it is absolutely a problem with the interpolating function.

So let's evaluate the following code in versions 10.2 and 10.31

```
Import["http://bit.ly/cp103issue"];
{sol1, sol2} = testSolution;
grid = testSolution[[1]]["Grid"];
vals1 = testSolution[[1]]["ValuesOnGrid"];
vals2 = testSolution[[2]]["ValuesOnGrid"];
norm = Norm /@ Transpose[{vals1, vals2}];
normgrid = Transpose[Append[Transpose[grid], norm]];
```

So I have extracted the grid points from the interpolating functions, as well as the values on those grid points.  I have checked, and they are the same across both versions to within an accuracy of 10^-17.  So we should be dealing with the same interpolating functions.  But we aren't.

Here is the nail in the coffin,

```
ListPlot[sol1 @@@ grid - vals1]
ListPlot[sol2 @@@ grid - vals2]
```

Evaluating this code in version 10.2, we get

[image]

which looks great.  In 10.3.1 we get

[image]

which is just plain horrible.  So what we have here is some backsliding in the interpolating function resulting from an `NDSolve` call using a nonrectangular region.

Now here is something interesting, if you take those grid points and the values on the grid, and you make an interpolation function using `Interpolation`, then you get basically the same plot in both versions.

```
ContourPlot[
 Interpolation[Transpose[{grid, norm}], InterpolationOrder -> 1][x, 
  y], {x, y} ∈ testMesh]
```

[image]

Comment: Paging @user21 - here is some more interpolation madness!

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. I was near to confirm the same results. So practically speaking, with `ListPlot[sol1 @@@ grid - vals1]` test you are proving that the `InterpolatingFunction` doesn't even interpolate on the grid points?

Comment: @unlikely - yes!!  The most basic thing you can expect from an interpolating function.

Comment: Thanks Jason; I think paging only works if I had a contribution on this particular site already; in any case I did not get a notification. But I certainly will have a look what goes wrong.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** This is fixed in Version 11.0:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
{Ri, Ro} = {3000000., 6371000.};
rgn = RegionDifference[Disk[{0., 0.}, Ro], Disk[{0., 0.}, Ri]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[rgn];
grid = mesh["Coordinates"];
vog = (Exp[-Norm[#]^2/Ri^2]) & /@ grid;
(*ListContourPlot[MapThread[Append,{grid,vog}],Epilog\[Rule]{Point[\
grid]},PlotLegends\[Rule]Automatic]*)

if = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, vog];
(*ContourPlot[if[x,y],{x,y}\[Element]mesh,PlotLegends\[Rule]Automatic,\
Epilog\[Rule]{Point[grid]}]*)
TakeLargest[(if @@@ grid - vog), 20]

{4.996*10^-16, 4.85723*10^-16, 4.44089*10^-16, 3.88578*10^-16, 
 3.33067*10^-16, 3.33067*10^-16, 2.498*10^-16, 2.498*10^-16, 
 2.22045*10^-16, 2.22045*10^-16, 2.22045*10^-16, 2.22045*10^-16, 
 2.22045*10^-16, 1.94289*10^-16, 1.66533*10^-16, 1.66533*10^-16, 
 1.66533*10^-16, 1.66533*10^-16, 1.66533*10^-16, 1.66533*10^-16}
```

**Old message:**

This is a bug; you can workaround that by setting

```
SetSystemOptions[ "FiniteElementOptions" -> {"CacheInterpolationElements" -> False}]
```

Update:

It seems the default tolerance is not high enough for mesh over a large space compared to the default bounding box:

```
SetSystemOptions[
 "FiniteElementOptions" -> {"InterpolationToleranceFactor" -> 10^-8}]
```

This would allow you to still make use of cached elements which is faster for structured queries (which *Plot is not)

Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry? Wait, is this your fault? [Grab the pitchforks](https://www.reddit.com/r/pitchforkemporium). :-)

Comment: @JasonB, sometimes things just get out of control....

Comment: Both workaround works to fix the aspect of my plots. But no one, apparently, fix the numerical problem exposed in the @JasonB answer (`InterpolatingFunction` that doesn't interpolate), at least in my specific case: `ifn=Import["http://bit.ly/1ThEi3G"];ifn["ValuesOnGrid"]-ifn@@@ifn["ElementMesh"]["Coordinates"]//Abs//Max` is not 0... It's `10^-2` w.r.t. the order of magnitude of `ifn` values on grid...

Comment: @unlikely, what do you get 0?, what OS, and $Version?

Comment: @unlikely - [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ie8qd.png) is what I get when I evaluate `ListPlot[ifn["ValuesOnGrid"] - ifn @@@ ifn["Grid"], PlotRange -> All]`.  And when I evaluate `MinMax[ifn["ValuesOnGrid"] - ifn @@@ ifn["Grid"]]` I get `{-3.1225*10^-16, 3.1225*10^-16}`

Comment: @unlikely, in version 10.4.1 I get something different: {-0.073572, 0.096867} and with '"CacheInterpolationElements" -> False' {-0.000306072, 0.000123037}

Comment: @JasonB, hm, this is suspicious. What OS an $version do you have?

Comment: @JasonB and @user21... With `10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)` and `SetSystemOptions[
 "FiniteElementOptions" -> {"CacheInterpolationElements" -> False}]` I get `0.000306072`. If I not did some mistake the result should be near zero or exactly zero...

Comment: @user21 - I'm using version 10.4 Linux, and [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KLQUP.png) are the results.  You have to use the ``"InterpolationToleranceFactor"`` option from this answer to get the correct result.

Comment: @JasonB, for some reason this does not work on linux 10.4.1. You can get it to work in that version with using `ifn = Import["http://bit.ly/1ThEi3G"]; DumpSave["~/ifn.mx", ifn]; Get["~/ifn.mx"]`. In the development version all 4 cases give `{-3.1225*10^-16, 3.1225*10^-16}`.